# MongoDB query: Filter inside dictionary elements

Tags: mongodb, filter, pymongo

I have a dictionary field in documents.

A sample document with **"countries"** field:

```
...
"countries": {
    "us": {
        "uid": "725129b4-debe-47dc-9ab0-aa8aa620e35b"
    },
    "canada": {
        "uid": "83250bc5-49ae-4775-a933-d7a3e9d00d1c"
    },
    "uk": {
        "path": "/uk/",
        "uid": "e32347a9-522c-4c66-be3b-3edfd50c76bb"
    },
    "spain": {
        "path": "/spain/",
        "uid": "93ecd56b-1ed2-4647-bee8-8685183eca2e"
    },
    "india": {
        "path": "/india/",
        "uid": "c4458535-c63b-45e1-bb24-cabbc65d59a4"
    }
}
...
```

From all documents i need to get the countries which have **"path"** attribute present?

Comment: Quick question: could you transform `countries` into an array of dictionaries, like this `[{'key': 'us', 'uid': '725129b4-debe-47dc-9ab0-aa8aa620e35b'}, {'key': 'canada', ...} ... ]`? It'll be much easier to construct the query in this case.

Comment: I understand it can help but I cant do that, its being used in many place. And the existing structure suits our needs

Answer (score 0):

While changing the data structure would be the best choice (as the query would be far more efficient and wouldn't require a secondary collection -- even double storing it as you save a document might be better), you could try a MapReduce to get the results if you can't change your data structure. You may need to do incremental updates and be aware that the results may not be always up to date.

Here's a simple version (in JavaScript):

```
map = function () {
    // loop through the countries node
    if (this.countries) {
        for(var name in this.countries) {
            if (typeof this.countries[name].path !== 'undefined') {
            // emit a unique combo id so that the reduce will only have
            // one value to reduce later
            emit({id: this._id, country: name}, this.countries[name].path);
            }
        }
    }
};

reduce = function(key, values) {
    // return the one value
    return values;
};
```

Then, run the reduce:

```
db.so.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "so_map"})
```

Produces something like (given your sample data):

```
> db.so_map.find()
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5183e08be71ddfd99756386c"), "country" : "india" }, "value" : "/india/" }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5183e08be71ddfd99756386c"), "country" : "spain" }, "value" : "/spain/" }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5183e08be71ddfd99756386c"), "country" : "uk" }, "value" : "/uk/" }
```